# Unable To Insert SQL into SQL Server Database with Python + PYODBC Error- Unable To Bind SQL Parameter

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I can't seem to get past this error. The code worked and it inserted the records into the database right up until I added extra parameters for the number, promote_tag and routevdn. Before when those were hard coded into the SQL it worked fine but for some reason now with those I get an error.

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Sean Project.py", line 48, in <module>

    add_number()

  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Sean Project.py", line 42, in add_number

    cursor.execute(update_query, pkey, number, numberTwo, promote_tag)

pyodbc.Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

Code:

```
    def add_number():
        number = input("Number to add: ")
        producerNumber = input("Producer Number: ")
        routevdn = "+1234567891"
        now = datetime.now()
        today = now.strftime("%m/%d")
        promote_tag = producerNumber + "-Lead-" + today
        query = """select max (pkey+1) from table_test"""
        print(promote_tag)
        print(routevdn)
        print(number)
        cursor.execute(query)
        for row in cursor:
            row_to_list = [elem for elem in row]
            pkey = row_to_list
            print(pkey)
        query_calltype = """select max (pkey+1) from table2_test"""
        cursor.execute(query_calltype)
        for row in cursor:
            row_to_list2 = [elem for elem in row]
            pkey_calltype = row_to_list2
            print(pkey_table2_test)

        update_query = """INSERT INTO table_test
    VALUES ((?), (?), (?), 'MY AGENCY NAME', '0', '0', '', (?), '0', '', '0', '', '',    '1', '', '0', '0', '', '', '', '1', '', '0', '', '', '', '',        '', '', '', '0', 'NULL');"""

        update_queryTwo = """INSERT INTO table2_test
        VALUES ((?), 'XX', '', (?), '', 'No', '', '', '', '', '0', (?), (?), '0', '', 'false', '', '0', '', '', '', '0', '0', '', '0', '', '', '0', 'NULL', 'NULL');"""
        cursor.execute(update_query, pkey, number, number, promote_tag)
        cursor.execute(update_queryTwo, pkey_calltype, routevdn, number, promote_tag)
        conn.commit()

    

    add_number()
```

Comment: What type is 'pkey' and 'pkey_calltype'?  Looks like an array or somesuch.

Comment: I just checked with print type and they are <class 'list'> but the pkey worked fine the script didnt break until I added the other variables @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: No idea, but it shouldn't be a list.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I think you are on to something, I removed the other variables and only left pkey and its working again, then I removed pkey and added the other variables back in and its working that way. It must be because pkey is a list. I remember I did it this way because when I fetch pkey with my select max pkey query its returning to my python variable as a row item and I didnt know how to convert it to string

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't generate keys like that.  If multiple sessions do it, you'll get failures or duplicates.  Instead use a SEQUENCE object or IDENTITY column.  With a SEQUENCE you can generate the key in a default or a query like `select next value for seq_tfndnis_test`.

Comment: Why are you re-inventing the wheel with `MAX + 1`? You should just use an `IDENTITY` column or a `SEQUENCE`

Comment: Thank you for that info @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I tried to get the pkey using that select statment of yours but cant quite figure out how to get it to work, just in SQL at the moment not even python

Answer (score 0):

What you pass to `execute` must be a tuple:

```
   cursor.execute(update_query, (pkey, number, number, promote_tag))
   cursor.execute(update_queryTwo, (pkey_calltype, routevdn, number, promote_tag))
```

By the way, do not use `(?)` in your query.  The substitution character is just `?`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @TimRoberts I tried adding them as a tuple but it still throws the same error at me, I have removed my redundant () around my placeholder ?

Comment: I notice you're using quoted `'0' and 'false' and 'NULL'`.  Those are very different values from `0 and false and NULL`.  Do you really want strings there?  And if `pkey` and `pkey_calltype` are lists, that's a problem.  It needs to be one value.

Comment: Yep it was the lists that were the issue, I changed the code for pkey = row_to_list to pkey = row_to_list[0] and its working fine now